# Why do I get a "Get-_InternalAdcsConfigurationState is not recognized" error when uninstalling the ADCS role?

Tags: networking, powershell, active-directory, windows-server, windows-server-2016

Where do I begin, I decided to set up a virtual network on VMware at home to play around with while I'm not at college where I study Networking and make virtual networks all the time and well my DC just keeps running into issues.

Firstly I couldn't install roles but I fixed that by installing ADCS. Now I can't uninstall ADCS. It's giving me an error message saying that it's trying to use a powershell command called `Get-_InternalAdcsConfigurationState` and that it's not recognized. I can't even find a command similar to that anywhere and I have no clue how to fix it. (What command would have a dash and underscore like that anyway unless someone is playing a prank on me or something)

As well as that I am getting an error message across all of my services I have set up which is "Cannot get event data".

I have google searched for ages and have found nothing related to either of these problems and its making me want to rip my hair out, any help would be appreciated.

[image: ADCS GUI Error]

[image: ADCS Powershell Error]

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: I've tried to improve the formatting a bit to make it easier to read. Please check to make sure it's still correct and I haven't changed the meaning! Consider asking about the event data issue as a separate question - though it might be related to this one so I've left it in. As for the naming, it's a fairly common convention to name internal/private commands (those that aren't supposed to be visible/callable outside of specific scripts) with an underscore prefix.

Comment: That said, this sounds ... quite broken. Have you at some point manually edited any files or registry entries? Consider re-installing the server and documenting every action you take so you can try to figure out what might have led to this issue (it's also good for future review, especially as you're learning to set one up) (and a good general habit to get into so you don't wonder, two years later, how exactly the server was set up).

Answer (score 0):

Simply install the feature and then uninstall it.

```
Install-WindowsFeature AD-Certificate

Uninstall-WindowsFeature AD-Certificate
```